# How to get different applications to share outbound port 80 in apache

Tags: html, apache, iframe, web, xampp

I'm trying to have a portal which combines all my applications running on a XAMPP server to only use port 80 for incoming connections.

For example if I'm at McDonald's and would like to login to my many programs which runs on, say, port 60443, and 60444, etc..., but McDonald's wifi blocks all non-port 80 traffic. Which prevents those applications to be accessed. How do I setup apache to behave the way I'd like?

Currently, I have a webpage which loads all the services in an iframe on my main site. Which works on most networks but not all. I'd like to remedy this, preferably using a best practice type setup, I've searched and I've not found any resources on how to go about programming apache to handle this. I'm thinking that this is because I'm not sure what this practice is called.

I would be very grateful if I could get some help on this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Edit* After some more searching, it appears that mod_proxy and virtual hosts are what I'm looking for.

Comment: my opinion, apache serve your request on listen port, if you want to block other, firewall in some router should fixed for you.

Comment: @ntaloventi I'm sorry if I inferred that I was looking to block traffic, this is not the case. I appreciate your response, but am looking to funnel all traffic over port 80, despite the port number used internally, not restrict it.